# my Virtual Private Server does not seem to have a port

Tags: node.js, express, vps

I just ordered a VPS on a hoster (ionos) and when I deploy my website with express.js it works on local but not on my server... I tried

```
console.log(process.env.PORT)
```

and I get "undefined".
This is the first time i work in a VPS, can someone help me?

So when I browse my website, I see "This site can’t be reached"

I checked my server firewall and i see port 80, 22 and 443 all being authorized...

I went as far as typing my server IP and still get "This site can’t be reached" error

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I forgot to point my domain to my DNS... Did it and now all working like a charm